# How can I get a secure connection using selenium server standalone to run IDE test on https website?

Tags: security, selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-server

When running

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "https://example.com/" "testSuitePath.html" "logPath.html"`

from command line, firefox stops me, saying,

"This connection is untrusted. You have asked Firefox to connect securely to example.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure. Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified."

First, why does this happen?
Second, how can I remedy this without saying "I understand the risks" and bypassing the page? (I would like it to be as secure as normal).